# Distribution given by a measure

Tags: distribution-theory

If $T$ is a distribution of order $0$ then it is true that it is given by measure?

Can anyone please help me how to prove this.
Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is or order $0$, then for each compact $K$ there is a $C>0$ such that $|T(\phi)|\leq C|\phi|$. This means that $T$ is a continuous functional on $C(K)$, i.e. an element of the dual of this Banach space.

Comment: @ Mlazhinka Shung Gronzalez LeWy how will we say that if it is in the dual then it is given by the measure?

Comment: [Using this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).

Comment: @OR. don't the fact that $T$ is of zero-th order tells us that $T(\phi) \leq C \sup |\phi|$ on compact sets, the same constante $C > 0$ for every compact? Does this implies the inequality that you wrote?